# Explain why V is equal to a span

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be the subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ that is given by the set of solutions to the homogeneous linear equation with the augmented matrix [1 2 3 | 0]

Explain why $\text{span}\{(0, 3, -2), (2, -1, 0)\}$ is equal to V ?

Can anyone explain to me how this work, all help is really appreciate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In set notation, $$V:=\{(a,b,c) \in \Bbb R^3:a+2b+3c=0\} $$ Here, $a+2b+3c=0$ is a single linear equation with THREE unknowns.  So arbitrarily assign *two*  values for $b$ and $c$, say for ex, put $b=t$ and $c=k$, then the solution set $S$  is $$S=\Bigg\{\Big(-2t-3k,t,k\Big): t,k \in \Bbb R\Bigg\}$$ That is, $$S=\Bigg\{t\Big (-2,1,0\Big)+k\Big (-3,0,1\Big): t,k \in \Bbb R\Bigg\}$$

Can you conclude now ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really help me understand the problem

Comment: put $t=3$ and $k=-2$ for obtaining your first vector (0,3,-2). Also put $t=-1$ and $k=0$ to obtain your second vector, So, in conclusion, $$\text{span}\{(-2,1,0),(-3,0,1)\}=V=\text{span}\{(0,3,-2),(2,-1,0)\}$$